# Does having a lot of inner 'helper' functions inside a functional stateless react component will result in worse performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native

I am trying to use React Hooks at all time so I avoid using classes. During the recent code review one of my coworkers recommended me rewriting my component using a class component instead of a functional component that used Hooks. His argument was that every time that my component is rendered all the 'inner member functions' are created again and that might result in worse performance. I was under the impression that React team wanted people to ditch classes whenever possible. Does having a lot of helper functions inside of a stateless functional component would really result in bad performance?

```
const Foo = () => {
   const helper = () => {
      doSomething()
   }
   return (<View />)
 }

OR

class Bar extends Component {
   helper = () => {
      doSomething()
   }
   render() {
      return (<View/>)
   }
}
```

Comment: When the argument is "it might hurt performance", the first response is "we don't care about might. _does_ it hurt performance?" and then you do both, and do some performance analysis. Unless you build thousands of components, I would be very surprised if you found a significant difference, but _you should test that_ instead of asking people who can't =)

Comment: I'm not sure the React team want people to ditch classes. On the intro to hooks page: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html it is said that there are no plans to remove classes from React. Hooks are completely optional.

Comment: It would help a lot if your examples showed how you're *using* `helper`.

Answer (score 2):

With your first example, a new function object has to be created each time `Foo` runs. So that's memory churn you don't need unless the JavaScript engine can optimize it out. (Like almost all performance concerns, of course, it's the kind of thing to worry about when you have a performance problem. Although if you're doing this in a lot of small components, it can add up.)

Depending on what `helper` needs, you could define it outside your SFC and just use it within it.

```
// I'm assuming this is in a module, so it's not a global
const helper = () => {
    doSomething()
}

const Foo = () => {
    // Presumably you use `helper` here somewhere
    return (<View />)
}
```

If for some reason you're not using modules (!!), to avoid `helper` being global, you'd do the usual scoping thing. Perhaps:

```
const Foo = (() => {
    const helper = () => {
        doSomething()
    }

    return () => {
        // Presumably you use `helper` here somewhere
        return (<View />)
    }
})()
```

Comment: The React team is pretty clear on the fact that you need to do this if you want to use stateless+hooks, though (looking at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies, that's basically this question's code) so I'd assume that's still more than performant enough if it made it through beta without blowing up for Facebook itself.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Yeah, that's why I said *"...depending on what `helper` needs..."* The absense of any call to `helper` in the question makes it awkward. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your coworker is technically correct that the inner functions will be instantiated and bound on each call to `render()`, but unless you are rendering a very large number of components very frequently (as the result of rapid state changes or something), the total cost should be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The helper function you wrote will be recreated each time when your component renders. You don't have to define your helper function inside the component as you do. If you really want to use React Hooks in your project look at hooks that will suit your needs in different situations. For example, you could use `useCallback` if you need a helper function to call some actions on user interactions. Your code will be looked like this:

```
const Foo = () => {
   const helper = useCallback(() => {
      doSomething()
   }, []);
   return (<View />)
 }
```

This function will be created only on the first render. If your function depends on some props, you could pass these props as input values to `useCallback`. This callback will be recreated when something changes. For example:

```
const Foo = (props) => {
   const helper = useCallback(() => {
      doSomething(props.id);
   }, [props.id]);
   return (<View />)
 }
```